# Load Different View Based on Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser

Can anyone suggest a reliable way to load a different view depending on the current browser?

We have some markup on a view that is broken in IE. We'd like to load an alternate view in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Javascript

You can use an Internet Explorer conditional comment for this:

```
<![if !IE]>
 window.location.replace("http://www.newpage.foo/newpage.html");
<![endif]>
```

More Information: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments

## ASP.Net MVC

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
{
     }
```

Comment: Interesting. I was hoping for a server-side solution to serve up an entirely different MVC view.